# Excel 2010 Data Connection - Add Filter to Command Text

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Two relevant workbooks:

- `Historical Data.xlsx` with a table `GLDATA`, which includes a field `cc`
- `Template.xlsx` with a named range `COSTCENTER`

Question: How do I modify the Command Text in the Data Connections Properties dialog box (using either SQL or Table syntax) to only pull those records from `GLDATA` into `Template.xlsx` where `cc = COSTCENTER`

**What have I tried so far**

SQL Syntax: `SELECT * FROM GLDATA WHERE GLDATA.cc = COSTCENTER`

**Closest solution I've found**

How to add parameters to an external data query in Excel which can't be displayed graphically?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11333955/290443

Comment: Its not clear from your question, but I'm guessing that the named range COSTCENTER contains a list of values which exist in the field cc?

Comment: It refers to just one cell, which has the value of the cost center I want to filter on.

Answer (score 0):

The field contains the string COSTCENTER? If so, try this:

SQL Syntax: SELECT * FROM GLDATA WHERE (GLDATA.cc = 'COSTCENTER')

Answer (score 0):

I would resolve this with the Power Query Add-In.

First build a simple Query to get the COSTCENTER named range data from the Excel Template file. Note this approach allows multiple COSTCENTER values to be listed.

Then start another Query from a simplified SQL Query e.g. `SELECT * FROM GLDATA`. Then add a Merge step to connect to the first Query on CC = COSTCENTER, and check the option to Only Keep Matching Rows.

From the Data ribbon, choose Refresh All to refresh the data if the COSTCENTER value or SQL input data changes.